# Making Python scripts work with xargs

Tags: python, xargs

What would be the process of making my Python scripts work well with 'xargs'?  For instance, I would like the following command to work through each line of text file, and execute an arbitrary command:

```
cat servers.txt | ./hardware.py -m
```

Essentially would like each line to be passed to the hardware.py script.

Comment: What you show there is *standard input*, but what you *ask* is `xargs`. They are not the same thing. Which did you want?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't just read in the text file in python?

Comment: The pipe just connects the `cat` `stdout` to the hardware.py `stdin`. So, in hardware.py, you should just read the data from the `stdin` (e.g. data = raw_input()).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make your commands work with `xargs` you simply need them to accept arguments. Arguments in Python are in the `sys.argv` list. In this way you can execute somthing like:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 ./myscript.py
```

which might be equivalent to

```
./myscript.py ./foo.txt ./biz/foobar.txt ./baz/yougettheidea.txt
```

To make your commands work with standard input, you can also use the `sys` module, this time with `sys.stdin`, which you can treat as a file. This is more like the example you gave:

```
./myscript.py < somefile.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing two issues.

First, your application can receive input from stdin. This has nothing to do with `xargs`. In your example, all `hardware.py` needs to do is read `sys.stdin` as the input file, e.g.:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    for line in sys.stdin:
         do_something(line)
```

If you want hardware.py to produce output that other programs down the line can use, just write to `sys.stdout`

Second, your application can receive input from arguments. This is where you would use `xargs`. For example:

xargs ./hardware.py < servers.txt # same as cat servers.txt | xargs ./hardware.py

This would pass every "word" of servers.txt (not every *line*) as an argument to hardware.py (possibly multiple arguments at once). This would be the same as running `hardware.py word1 word2 word3 word4 ...`

Python stores command line arguments in the `sys.arvg` array. `sys.argv[0]` will be the command name, and `sys.argv[1:]` will be all the command line arguments.  However, you are usually better off processing your command line using [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what you want to do. If `./hardware.py -m` reads one line from standard input, you can use GNU Parallel to distribute those lines:

```
cat servers.txt | parallel --pipe -N1 ./hardware.py -m
```

If `./hardware.py -m` takes a single server as argument you can do:

```
cat servers.txt | parallel ./hardware.py -m
```

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1