# using xargs (or sth else?) to sequentially execute a python script

Tags: python, xargs

This question is almost a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853169/making-python-scripts-work-with-xargs), but only almost, and none of the answers fit to what I a trying to achieve.

I want to do the following: have a list of filenames, execute a python script sequentially (!) with each filename. Now, I know I can easily parse the list of filenames in my python script and execute whatever function on each line, but the idea here is that I want to move that batch execution flexibility to the shell, and leave my python scripts unchanged.

So my file of arguments looks like this:

```
$ cat arglist
1                  # <- separated by newlines
2
3
4
```

the python script:

```
import sys
print("args received:",sys.argv)
```

I tried:

```
$ cat arglist | xargs python ./pyxargs.py -a -b -c
args received: ['./pyxargs.py', '-a', '-b', '-c', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

But what I am trying to achieve is the following

```
args received: ['./pyxargs.py', '-a', '-b', '-c', '1']
args received: ['./pyxargs.py', '-a', '-b', '-c', '2']
args received: ['./pyxargs.py', '-a', '-b', '-c', '3']
args received: ['./pyxargs.py', '-a', '-b', '-c', '4']
```

I guess the way how xargs works is just confusing me. Or is it simply the wrong tool, always combining the arguments and executing a single execution, instead of separate executions? If yes, what would be the appropriate alternative to xargs?

Thanks for help

Comment: Just add `-n 1` to the xargs invocation

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `-I`:

`< arglist xargs -I file python ./pyxargs.py -a -b -c file`

Note that this will fail if any of your filenames contains a newline, but that's inherent in trying to record filenames in a text file so this probably won't be an issue.

Comment: With -I, according to the documentation "unquoted blanks do not terminate input items;  instead the separator is the newline character".  This is safer than using -n since it will handle filenames with space in the name (but not newlines).

Comment: Although the more relevant quote from the documenation is "Execute utility for each input line", a line which does not appear in the man page on some linux distros.